# Display archives based in post_format

Tags: archives, post-formats

I'm working in a project that needs to use `post_formats`.

First of all, is there any way of create a new post format? The only thing I've found was to overwrite an existing one.

In addition, they're using 4 different post formats. So I need to display 4 archives based in those 4 post formats.
I found a way of displaying the archives like this : `mysite.com/type/post_format`

But it doesn't work for standard post_format -

For customizing those archives, is there any attribute that i could use in the conditional tag `is_archive`? like `is_archive(post_format)`?

I know this implementation is a little outdated and that if I use a system of tags and categories would be easier.

Would you recommend instead, create 3 different post types for this?

And if I do this, is there a way to display all the results of all post types into a one archive? and then each post type should have a specific archive.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot define your own post formats. This is on purpose. The post formats are [supposed to be standards](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats), so theme developers can include styles for them. That wouldn't work if people start making their own formats.

Essentially post formats are just a custom taxonomy added to posts. So testing for [post format archive pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax#Post_Formats) follow that route. Like this: `is_tax ('post_format', 'post-format-aside')`

If you want more flexibility you could [define your own custom taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy). You could even call it 'post formats' if you want to.